# sdk for changing LG monitor settings

Tags: macos, sdk, lg

I have an LG monitor connected to my laptop(it's a MacBook) and I would like to develop a software that can programmatically change settings like brightness and contrast of the monitor. Is there such SDK available?

Answer (score 0):

It's not SDK, but you could try to use [xrandr](https://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR) or [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) tool to modify your screen settings.

*(I'm not a developer of any of above)*